# UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout error even after providing a layout

Tags: ios, swift

Seeing the following Exception

```
'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

with this ViewController

```
import UIKit

class SelectDesignController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private let designCellId = "designCellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavBar()
        configureUI()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8515156507, green: 0.9521961808, blue: 0.9503603578, alpha: 1)
        collectionView.register(DesignCategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: designCellId)
    }
    @objc func handleDismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configureNavBar() {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .chevronLeft, style: .solid, textColor: .white, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))
    }
    func configureUI (){
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8515156507, green: 0.9521961808, blue: 0.9503603578, alpha: 1)
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: designCellId, for: indexPath) as! DesignCategoryCell
        return cell
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    /** PROVIDING a LAYOUT HERE **/
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }

}
```

I'm including `SelectDesignController` as follows:

```
let controller = SelectDesignController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
configureNav(nav: nav, title: "Designs")
present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Any idea, what am I missing ?

Comment: How are you initialising your SelectDesignController?. From code or StoryBoard?

Comment: I’m initializing it in Code (no storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You should check 2 things:

**frame**

The frame rectangle for the collection view, measured in points. The origin of the frame is relative to the superview in which you plan to add it. This frame is passed to the superclass during initialization.

**layout**

The layout object to use for organizing items. The collection view stores a strong reference to the specified object. Must not be nil.

Comment: I’m providing the layout in the last method collectionView